# Bug in Site Analytics/Traffic Sources?

Tags: support, bug, site-analytics

I just grabbed this picture from Site Analytics/Traffic Sources of [Economics Stack Exchange](https://economics.stackexchange.com/):

[image]

What strikes me as peculiar is that visits from all sites except Google are either **274** or a multiple of it (**274 \times 3 =822**).

**Is this a default value when traffic is too low or non-existent? Or...?**

Comment: Maybe 274 is the [301](http://www.businessinsider.com/this-is-why-all-new-youtube-videos-get-exactly-301-views-2013-8?international=true&r=US&IR=T) for analytics?

Comment: This is a result of sampling on Google Analytic's part. Sorry. :-(